# Configure TT_News

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tt-news

I'm searing for several hours but can not found an good example on how to configure the tt_news extension with typoscript. I would like to know how I can disable showing the date, cat info and archive to make it a simple overview. Also clicking on the news item does not show the single page? Can any one post an simple example of typoscript for configuring an simple news overview with the tt_news extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [tt_news documentation](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/tt_news/) will answer all your questions.

Your first issue is very simple to solve: just use your own templates and remove the corresponding marker.

1. Copy the template from tt_news/pi/tt_news_v2_template.html to somewhere else, e.g. into fileadmin/myproject/tt_news_v2_template.html
2. Configure tt_news with the new location of the template in your TypoScript Constants: `plugin.tt_news.file.templateFile = fileadmin/myproject/tt_news_v2_template.html` (you have to include the static TypoScript of tt_news too)

Your second issue seems to be a problem with the single pid configuration. You can solve this with defining your single page in the TypoScript Constants:

```
plugin.tt_news.singlePid = 123
```

It seems that you are new to TYPO3 and tt_news, so maybe you should simply follow the [quick start guide in the tt_news documentation](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/tt_news/ExtNews/UsersManual/QuickStart/Index.html).